# Echonest track profile requests always return an empty audio_summary

Tags: echonest

I'm requesting `bucket=audio_summary` for songs that rank highly in hotttness.
The top 100 hotttessst songs all return `track.status: 'complete'` but the audio summary is always an empty object.

How do I get audio summary data like `time_signature` and `tempo`? Doesn't `track.status: complete` imply that this information should be included in the response?

```
Can't Feel My Face 
https://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/track/profile?api_key=*****************&format=json&id=SOMVZDS14DDE5909E7&bucket=audio_summary

  {
    "response": {
      "status": {
        "version": "4.2",
        "code": 0,
        "message": "Success"
      },
      "track": {
        "status": "complete",
        "id": "SOZOIDR14C02B654D4",
        "audio_summary": {}
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the SongId rather than the TrackId for this song.  If you replace 'track' with 'song' in your query you get the expected results.

This:
    https://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/profile?api_key=*****************&format=json&id=SOMVZDS14DDE5909E7&bucket=audio_summary

Returns this:

```
{  
   "response":{  
      "status":{  
         "version":"4.2",
         "code":0,
         "message":"Success"
      },
      "songs":[  
         {  
            "artist_id":"ARYUDWF12F2B89BB33",
            "artist_name":"The Weeknd",
            "id":"SOMVZDS14DDE5909E7",
            "audio_summary":{  
               "key":9,
               "analysis_url":"http://echonest-analysis.s3.amazonaws.com/TR/A7NwGAWSmhnc53M8w1rLk-eA_tsN8OUHaqV5C5FTbb9BnCPZVnxWOGld1wLxJJ-xdNV8xKJbbZlCRSKJc%3D/3/full.json?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJRDFEY23UEVW42BQ&Expires=1454028841&Signature=HeUxbEJt4f0ncipjD1Gamtuj08E%3D",
               "energy":0.781735,
               "liveness":0.12022,
               "tempo":107.954,
               "speechiness":0.042317,
               "acousticness":0.124391,
               "instrumentalness":0.0,
               "mode":0,
               "time_signature":4,
               "duration":216.46667,
               "loudness":-5.528,
               "audio_md5":"",
               "valence":0.586261,
               "danceability":0.713659
            },
            "title":"Can't Feel My Face"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

The only reason I was able to track this down was that throwing any ID into the track API give back the stub response you were seeing and I was able to get the audio_summary for this song using the spotify id so I knew it was available.